# How to Find Union of Two String Arrays

Tags: java, arrays

I am trying to find the union of two string arrays.  I have created a new array and have copied all the data from the first set into the new array.  I am having trouble adding the information from the second set into the new array.

I need to use loops to search the second array and find the duplicates.  I keep getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

Here is my current code:

```
static String[] union(String[] set1, String[] set2) {
    String union[] = new String[set1.length + set2.length];

    int i = 0;
    int cnt = 0;

    for (int n = 0; n < set1.length; n++) {
        union[i] = set1[i];
        i++;
        cnt++;
    }

    for (int m = 0; m < set2.length; m++) {
        for (int p = 0; p < union.length; p++) {
            if (set2[m] != union[p]) {
                union[i] = set2[m];
                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    cnt++;

    union = downSize(union, cnt);

    return union;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

The standard way of doing intersections or unions is using a set. You should use the `Set` class from collections framework.

Create two arraylist objects for your two arrays.
 Define a Set    object.
 Add both the arraylist objects into the Set using `addAll`    method.

As set holds unique elements, the set forms the union of
    both arrays.

```
  //push the arrays in the list.
  List<String> list1 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray1));
  List<String> list2 = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(stringArray2));

  HashSet <String> set = new HashSet <String>();

  //add the lists in the set.
  set.addAll(list1);
  set.addAll(list2);

  //convert it back to array.
  String[] unionArray = set.toArray(new String[0]);
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `Set` is going to be one of the easiest way:

```
public static String[] unionOf(String[] strArr1, String[] strArr2) {
    Set<String> result = new HashSet<String>();
    result.addAll(Arrays.asList(strArr1));
    result.addAll(Arrays.asList(strArr2));
    return result.toArray(new String[result.size()]);
}
```

There are also other utilities that can help in similar work, e.g. Guava:

```
public static String[] unionOf(String[] strArr1, String[] strArr2) {
    return Sets.union(Sets.newHashSet(strArr1), 
                      Sets.newHashSet(strArr2))
               .toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have several problems with this part of your code:

```
for(int m = 0; m < set2.length; m++)
        for(int p = 0; p < union.length; p++)
            if(set2[m] != union[p])
            {   
                union[i] = set2[m];
                i++;        
            }
        cnt++;
```

First, you should be using `!equals()` instead of `!=` to compare strings. Second, despite the indenting, the statement `cnt++` is not part of the outer loop. You don't need both `i` and `cnt`; their values should always match. Finally, you are adding `set2[m]` once for each element of `union` that is different from it. You only want to add it once. Here's a version that should work:

```
static String[] union( String[] set1, String[] set2 )
{
    String union[] = new String[set1.length + set2.length];
    System.arraycopy(set1, 0, union, 0, set1.length); // faster than a loop
    int cnt = set1.length;
    for(int m = 0; m < set2.length; m++) {
        boolean found = false;
        for(int p = 0; p < union.length && !found; p++) {
            found = set2[m].equals(union[p]);
        }
        if(!found)
        {   
            union[cnt] = set2[m];
            cnt++;        
        }
    }
    union = downSize( union, cnt );
    return union;
}
```

As other posters have noted, an alternative approach is to use a `HashSet<String>`, add the elements found in the two arrays, and turn the result back into an array.

Comment: `boolean = set2[m].equals(union[p]);` - you probably meant: `found |= set2[m].equals(union[p]);`

Comment: Thank you for the direction. This has been very helpful. I understand my mistake and have a better idea of how to correct the error.

Comment: @alfasin - Oops. Thanks for pointing that out. Fixed now. One does not need `|=`, though; `=` will do since the body of the loop is not entered unless `found` is `false`.

Comment: Right, I missed the condition inside the for-loop... +1 :)

Answer (score 0):

You get ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException on this line:

```
union[i] = set2[m];
```

because you keep increasing `i` somewhere around: `set2.length * union.length` times (nested loops).

Doing what R.J wrote will not give you the union - you'll have many duplicate items since by doing: `set2[m].equals(union[p])` you compare every member of set2 to all the members of union and **for each** member that it's not equal to - you add it. so you end up adding the same items multiple times!

The right way to do it is like Deepak Mishra suggested by using `Set` which will "take care" of the duplicates.

Example:

```
int[] a = {1,2,3,4,5};
int[] b = {4,5,6,7};
Set union = new HashSet<Integer>();
for(int i=0; i<a.length; i++) union.add(a[i]);
for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++) union.add(b[i]);
Object[] ans = union.toArray();
for(int i=0; i<ans.length; i++)
    System.out.print(ans[i]+" ");
```

will output:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Since it's HW I won't write the code for the answer, but I'll give you a tip: 
doing it your way requires `O(n^2)` - if you'll think a bit I'm sure that you can find a way to do it in a better time, say,
 `O(n log n)`...

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate your guidance.  This has been VERY helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Though using the SETS is the best solution, here is a simple solution.

```
 private static String getUnion(String a, String b, boolean ignoreCase) {

    String union = "";

    if (a == null || b == null || a.length() < 1 || b.length() < 1) {
        return union;
    }

    char[] shortest;
    char[] longest;

    if (ignoreCase) {
        shortest = (a.length() <= b.length() ? a : b).toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        longest = (a.length() <= b.length() ? b : a).toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    } else {
        shortest = (a.length() <= b.length() ? a : b).toLowerCase().toCharArray();
        longest = (a.length() <= b.length() ? b : a).toLowerCase().toCharArray();
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    for (char c : shortest) {
        for (int i = 0; i < longest.length; i++) {
            if (longest[i] == c) {
                sb.append(c);
            }
        }
    }

    union = sb.toString();

    return union;
}
```

and following are few tests.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println("Union of '' and BXYZA is " + getUnion("", "BXYZA", true));
    System.out.println("Union of null and BXYZA is " + getUnion(null, "BXYZA", true));

    System.out.println("Union of ABC and BXYZA is " + getUnion("ABC", "BXYZA", true));
    System.out.println("Union of ABC and BXYZA is " + getUnion("ABC", "bXYZA", false));

}
```